# Apache keeps asking for 401 authorization

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

I am having a strange problem which I have never had before. I have freshly installed Linux (it's a little-known linux release based on Ubuntu, used in a narrow industry segment, I hope it itself doesn't matter much). I have Apache installed. Every time I am trying to open

```
http://localhost
```

(locally) I get 401 Authorization required response.

My /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order Allow,Deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The /var/www directory doesn't contain any .htaccess files. The /etc/apache2/apache2.conf configuration file doesn't contain anything containg text "auth".

File permissions for /var/www is: drwxrwxrwx, root:www (owner user - root, group www). The apache user "www-data" is a member of the group "www". The index file /var/www/index.html has the same permissions.

Content of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ is the following:

```
alias.conf            authz_user.load  dir.load          php5.load
alias.load            autoindex.conf   env.load          setenvif.conf
auth_basic.load       autoindex.load   mime.conf         setenvif.load
authn_file.load       cgi.load         mime.load         status.conf
authz_default.load    deflate.conf     negotiation.conf  status.load
authz_groupfile.load  deflate.load     negotiation.load
authz_host.load       dir.conf         php5.conf
```

Built-in modules (/usr/sbin/apache2 -l):

```
core.c
mod_authn_pam.c
mod_auth_basic.c
mod_log_config.c
mod_logio.c
prefork.c
http_core.c
mod_so.c
```

The interestign thing is that if I add the following line:

```
Satisfy Any
```

to the <Directory /> section in  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default file, every request generates the following error in Apache's error log:

```
[Mon Oct 01 12:34:59 2012] [notice] child pid 4445 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

and Apache returns nothing, just closes the connection.

I am completely lost, what makes Apache to ask for authorization, and even don't know how to debug it. Enabling debug level for the log files doesn't reveal anythin both in access.log and error.log. Any help or direction what to look at will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I contacted with this Linux vendors and it turned out that this particular Linux release is built in the way, that Apache authorization just can't be turned off, so there is no any way to switch it off except removing apache packages and replace them with other ones.